# Express show Cannot GET/ at post function on Nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have this code saved on my Nginx server with Let's Encrypt SSL.

My intention on this code is to be backend server.

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function(res, req) {
  res.send('GET ROOT');
});

app.post('/', function(res, req) {
  res.send('POST ROOT');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});
```

The code works great on local.

But when I deployed it on remote server, first I request GET `example.com/` it returned `GET ROOT`. Then I did POST `example.com/` it returned `GET ROOT`. It should be `POST ROOT`.

And this is my server config snippet from `sites-available`

```js
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen[::]: 80 default_server;

  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  }

  # some ssh default path
}
```

The server is successfully propagated with a domain, and I think there is no problem with loading index.html or something with GET function. And I run the js with nodemon at this development phase.

Please advice..

---

I thought it was about CORS and I put default CORS configuration, but still nothing's changed.
Then I add this `post` function without a `get` with a same endpoint.

```js
app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
  res.send('POST POST');
});
```

It returned this result

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
  <pre>Cannot GET /post</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

For Nginx error log when I do GET and POST request (retrieved from /var/log/nginx/error.log.1 )

```html
2017/10/24 16:27:19 [error] 1667#1667: *14 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 125.163.124.227, server: officially.id, request: "GET $
2017/10/24 20:52:06 [error] 1667#1667: *72 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 94.23.35.126, server: officially.id, request: "GET / H$
2017/10/24 21:43:26 [notice] 2556#2556: signal process started
2017/10/24 21:48:01 [error] 2758#2758: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 114.124.167.30, server: officially.id, request: "GET /t$
2017/10/24 21:57:04 [notice] 2877#2877: signal process started
2017/10/24 22:00:30 [emerg] 2919#2919: invalid value "=" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:53
2017/10/24 22:00:39 [emerg] 2924#2924: invalid value "=" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:53
2017/10/24 22:10:15 [notice] 3060#3060: signal process started
2017/10/25 03:34:42 [error] 3063#3063: *36 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.6.202.198, server: officially.id, request: "GET /xx$
```

When I tried to capture my app.js error and output, nothing is written there except string logged at `app.listen(...)`.

Comment: If you are not using `/socket.io` remove `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;` and `proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';`

Comment: Is there really a space in the middle of your `proxy_pass` URL?

Comment: @skirtle sorry it is a typo in the snippet only..

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes I am not using socket.io, I removed those lines as per your suggestions and reload Nginx. It still returned 200 but with GET result even when I request as POST..

Comment: Post your nginx logs

Comment: @TarunLalwani there you go.. it is weird that the request is not captured on log, both on nginx and forever log file. I am considering to reinstall my server

Comment: I think this may be a case of a redirect happening on POST which is not a valid thing to do?

Comment: the code is very simple. just to send result of a hard-coded string yet postman (and other software) failed to retrieve result from POST function. no logic code involved yet.